# Авторизация при помощи официального приложения Vkontakte Android

Tags: java, android, android-vksdk

Здравствуйте.
Пишу приложение для соцсети ВКонтакте.

Столкнулся с такой проблемой, - когда на устройстве есть активная сессия (т.е пользователь залогинен в офф. приложении), то моё приложение выдаёт ошибку о невалидности ключа приложения.

Если же пользователь не авторизован в официальном приложении, то моё приложение срабатывает отлично.

Следовательно, хотелось бы избежать такой ситуации, что пользователь должен выбирать, каким приложением пользоваться в данный момент, а просто авторизовавшись в официальном приложении - отдавал необходимую информацию моему приложению.

получение токена и инициализация происходит так

```
public class Application extends android.app.Application {

VKAccessTokenTracker vkAccessTokenTracker = new VKAccessTokenTracker() {
    @Override
    public void onVKAccessTokenChanged(VKAccessToken oldToken, VKAccessToken newToken) {
        if (newToken == null) {
            // VKAccessToken is invalid
            Intent intent = new Intent(Application.this, MainActivity.class);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
};

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    vkAccessTokenTracker.startTracking();
    VKSdk.initialize(this);
}
```

}

P.S. в разработке под Андроид новичок, поэтому могу чего-то и не знать, и прошу помощи.

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решилась добавление ещё одного `fingerprint` в консоль разработчика приложения ВКонтакте.